# Debian x86_64 and 4 GB RAM

Tags: linux, ram, x86

I bought additional 2GB of RAM and inserted it into my laptop.
The BIOS sees 4GB of RAM but Linux sees only 3GB.

Output of `free -m`:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3009       1158       1850         14         37        304
 -/+ buffers/cache:       816       2192
Swap:         3942          0       3942
```

I found that a 32-bit linux doesn't see 4GB of RAM. But when I downloaded Debian I chose amd64, I think that mean it's a 64-bit architecture. The command `uname -a` says that it is a x86_64 architecture.

```
Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u1 (2015-12-14) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My question is what I should do in order to solve this problem?

Edit: 
I have Chinese laptop Tsinghua Tongfang k46A
content of /var/log/kern.log can be found here (it is too long for post here)
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/Mz21/nERCLHFFT

Comment: amd64 = x86_64. Your kernel is capable of seeing 4GB of RAM or more, but it's only found 3GB. The figure 3009MB is what's left for applications after hardware peripherals (e.g. the graphic card) and the kernel itself have taken their share. Your data is consistent with a graphic card taking 1GB of memory, but that's surprisingly large for a laptop. There may be more cluse in the kernel logs; please post the content of `/var/log/kern.log` for a full boot (starting with the first line after the last boot, and up to the time when you logged in). Also tell us what laptop model you have.

Comment: I add it in question. I would be very strange if graphic card use 1gb, because when I use 2gb RAM system saw 1.9 gb.